# Access to class generated with XSD

Tags: c#, .net, soap, xsd, xsd2code

I've issue with **access to property** of my generated class.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<e:Envelope xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
 xmlns:w="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"
 xmlns:dn="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl">
  <e:Header>
    <w:MessageID>uuid:84ede3de-7dec-11d0-c360-f01234567890</w:MessageID>
    <w:To e:mustUnderstand="true">urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:ws:2005:04:discovery</w:To>
    <w:Action mustUnderstand="true">
      http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery/Probe
    </w:Action>
  </e:Header>
  <e:Body>
    <d:Probe>
      <d:Scopes></d:Scopes>
      <d:Types>dn:NetworkVideoTransmitter</d:Types>
    </d:Probe>
  </e:Body>
</e:Envelope>
```

This is my generated xsd (one of three):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="Envelope" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:mstns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft
com:xml-msdata" attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:app1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
xmlns:app2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery">
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery" schemaLocation="Probe_app2.xsd" />
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" schemaLocation="Probe_app1.xsd" />
  <xs:attribute name="mustUnderstand" msdata:Prefix="e" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:element name="Envelope" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:Locale="en-US" msdata:Prefix="e">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Header" msdata:Prefix="e">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="app1:MessageID" minOccurs="0" />
                  <xs:element ref="app1:To" />
              <xs:element ref="app1:Action" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="Body" msdata:Prefix="e">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="app2:Probe" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And finally this is my generated class from xsd2code:

```
namespace PROBE
{
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{

    private List<object> itemsField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    public Envelope()
    {
        this.itemsField = new List<object>();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Body", typeof(EnvelopeBody), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Header", typeof(EnvelopeHeader), Order = 0)]
    public List<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
public partial class EnvelopeBody
{

    private Probe probeField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    public EnvelopeBody()
    {
        this.probeField = new Probe();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery", Order = 0)]
    public Probe Probe
    {
        get
        {
            return this.probeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.probeField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvelopeBody));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery")]
public partial class Probe
{

    private string scopesField;

    private string typesField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 0)]
    public string Scopes
    {
        get
        {
            return this.scopesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.scopesField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order = 1)]
    public string Types
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typesField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typesField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Probe));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
public partial class EnvelopeHeader
{

    private string messageIDField;

    private To toField;

    private Action actionField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    public EnvelopeHeader()
    {
        this.actionField = new Action();
        this.toField = new To();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", Order = 0)]
    public string MessageID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.messageIDField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.messageIDField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", IsNullable = true, Order = 1)]
    public To To
    {
        get
        {
            return this.toField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.toField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing", IsNullable = true, Order = 2)]
    public Action Action
    {
        get
        {
            return this.actionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.actionField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(EnvelopeHeader));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing")]
public partial class To
{

    private string mustUnderstandField;

    private string valueField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope")]
    public string mustUnderstand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mustUnderstandField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mustUnderstandField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(To));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.233")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing")]
public partial class Action
{

    private string mustUnderstandField;

    private string valueField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string mustUnderstand
    {
        get
        {
            return this.mustUnderstandField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.mustUnderstandField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(Action));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I've no problem with Deserialization, it created proper class, but I don't know, **how to access to properties.**
I was trying something like that:

```
PROBE.Envelope env = PROBE.Envelope.Deserialize(xmlString);
env.Items[0].MessageID = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
```

but it is wrong.

(*Error   33  'object' does not contain a definition for 'MessageID' and no extension method 'MessageID' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*)

I'm including [link](http://2i.cz/c0302f05d6) to picture for better understanding of class structure.
I will be grateful for any advice, thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason your `Items` property is of type object, but it should be `EnvelopeHeader`. Check your xsd file if you have defined all types correctly.

Or you can cast:

```
  ((EnvelopeHeader)env.Items[0]).MessageID = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Comment: Yes, I think it's fine, because Item[0] is EnvelopeHeader type and Item[1] is EnvelopeBody type...